# wxWidgets - Blocking window modal dialogs on OS X

Tags: c++, c++14, wxwidgets

I'm in the process of porting an old application of mine (made in wxWidgets 3.0.2 and targeting Windows) to macOS now. My application is a code editor, and when closing the application, I wanted to ask if the user wanted to save.

```
switch (dialog->ShowModal())
{
    case wxID_YES:
        OnMenuSave(e);

        // Only break if the file is not saved
        // The user must have clicked on cancel button in save as box
        if (!editorPage->CodeChanged())
            break;

    case wxID_CANCEL:
        e.Veto();
        dialog->Destroy();
        return;
}
```

This used to work fine, but however I wanted to show the dialogs the mac way, like they used to be attached to the window they are created from.

So when I wrote the helper function to use the `ShowWindowModalThenDo` function on the dialog.

```
template <typename Functor>
inline void ShowWindowModalThenDo(wxDialog *dlg, const Functor& onEndModal)
{
#ifdef __WXMAC__
    dlg->ShowWindowModalThenDo(onEndModal);
#else
    onEndModal(dlg->ShowModal());
#endif
}
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't pause the event, while the dialog is being shown. This is especially problematic as I handle this in the editor closing event. So even when the dialog is being shown, and allows for the user to click on cancel, the editor page is getting closed.

How can I temporarily pause the events from processing on the parent window?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show a modal dialog as a sheet, you don't need to use `ShowWindowModalThenDo()`, just check that your dialog has the window that should be used as the sheet parent as parent.

Comment: It is set as the parent indeed. I made sure by calling `dialog->SetParent(wxGetTopLevelWindow(this))` too.